# How to save this JSON stringified array into database?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a form that submitted a stringified JSON array. This is the data example:

```
"[{'name':'i_cp_nm','value':'1'},{'name':'i_cp_tp','value':'2'},{'name':'i_cp_mb','value':'3'},{'name':'i_cp_em','value':'4'},{'name':'i_cp_jb','value':'5'},{'name':'i_cp_nt','value':'6'},{'name':'i_cp_nm','value':'7'},{'name':'i_cp_tp','value':'8'},{'name':'i_cp_mb','value':'9'},{'name':'i_cp_em','value':'10'},{'name':'i_cp_jb','value':'11'},{'name':'i_cp_nt','value':'12'}]";
```

This is the desired inserted data looks like:

```
i_cp_jd     i_cp_nm     i_cp_tp     i_cp_mb     i_cp_em     i_cp_jb     i_cp_nt
    xxx           1           2           3           4           5           6
    xxx           7           8           9          10          11          12
```

This is the current loop, but I do not know if this is right:

```
$arr_cp = //arr_data



    foreach($arr_cp as $val_cp){
        $dt_cp['i_cp_jd']   = $this->input->post('i_v_id');

        //didn't know what to do here

        $this->model_vendor->insert_vendor_pic($dt_cp);

    }
```

the the insert method:

```
function insert_vendor_pic($dt_cp){
    $query = $this->db->insert('vendordetail_pic',$dt_cp);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Post code of insert_vendor_pic() function

Comment: @usmanikram I've add it

Comment: @Shota please use json_decode($arr_cp, TRUE) because it is JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function for prepare/convert your input to matrix:

```
function prepareData($rawData) {
    $rawData = str_replace("'", '"', $rawData);

    $data = array();
    foreach(json_decode($rawData, true) as $d) {
            if (!isset($data[$d['name']])) {
                $data[$d['name']] = array();
            }
            $data[$d['name']][] = $d['value'];
    }

    $rows = array();
    foreach ($data as $col => $values) {
        foreach ($values as $i => $v) {
            if (!isset($rows[$i])) {
                $rows[$i] = array();
            }
            $rows[$i][$col] = $v;
        }
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

### Convert:

```
$rawData = "[{'name':'i_cp_nm','value':'1'},{'name':'i_cp_tp','value':'2'},{'name':'i_cp_mb','value':'3'},{'name':'i_cp_em','value':'4'},{'name':'i_cp_jb','value':'5'},{'name':'i_cp_nt','value':'6'},{'name':'i_cp_nm','value':'7'},{'name':'i_cp_tp','value':'8'},{'name':'i_cp_mb','value':'9'},{'name':'i_cp_em','value':'10'},{'name':'i_cp_jb','value':'11'},{'name':'i_cp_nt','value':'12'}]";
print_r(prepareData($rawData));
```

### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [i_cp_nm] => 1
            [i_cp_tp] => 2
            [i_cp_mb] => 3
            [i_cp_em] => 4
            [i_cp_jb] => 5
            [i_cp_nt] => 6
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [i_cp_nm] => 7
            [i_cp_tp] => 8
            [i_cp_mb] => 9
            [i_cp_em] => 10
            [i_cp_jb] => 11
            [i_cp_nt] => 12
        )

)
```

Finally you can simple insert this data to DB any way you like.

Comment: This works. But, kinda complicated. is this can be simplified?

Comment: I think yes. Try :)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$arr_cp = json_decode($yourJsonData, true);
```

Comment: sorry for slow respon. But, how do I do the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it systematically then you should use an appropriate JSON parser/ deserializer to create an instance of the domain or whatever you are supposed to create from that form data and insert those instances in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it systematically then you should use a appropriate JSON parser/ deserializer to create an instance of the domain or whatever you are supposed to create from that form data and insert that in DB.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the json format, so you have to decode json into array by using

```
$arr_cp = json_decode($arr_cp, TRUE);
```

then do $arr_cp into foreach loop

```
foreach($arr_cp as $val_cp){
        $dt_cp['i_cp_jd']   = $this->input->post('i_v_id');

        //didn't know what to do here

        $this->model_vendor->insert_vendor_pic($dt_cp);

    }
```